# Drupal 8 table sticky parameter not working. How to solve?

Tags: drupal-8

In drupal 7 it was no problem to make sticky header.
But in D8 - something is wrong.

My code:

```
$out = array();

    $rows = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 700; $i++) {
            $rows[$i]['ID'] = ['data' => $i];
            $rows[$i]['name'] = "user_" . $i;
            $rows[$i]['some'] = rand(0,634);
    }

    $out['table'] = [
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#header' => ['ID', 'Name', 'Rand'],
        '#sticky' => true,
        '#caption' => 'Table caption',
    ];

    return $out;
```

Answer (score 4):

In drupal 7:

```
$out['table'] = [
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#header' => ['ID', 'Name', 'Rand'],
    '#sticky' => true,
    '#caption' => 'Table caption',
];
```

In drupal 8:

```
$out['table'] = [
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#header' => ['ID', 'Name', 'Rand'],
    '#sticky' => true,
    '#caption' => 'Table caption',
];
```

Use #type in drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

In [Drupal Twig Template Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!table.html.twig/8.2.x) they are providing Sticky option. You can check with that.

For Sticky header you can check with [this.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!themes!stable!css!system!components!sticky-header.module.css/8.2.x)

Twig Template provide following options for table.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a table.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the <table> tag.
 * - caption: A localized string for the <caption> tag.
 * - colgroups: Column groups. Each group contains the following properties:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the <col> tag.
 *     Note: Drupal currently supports only one table header row, see
 *     https://www.drupal.org/node/893530 and
 *     http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7#comment-5109.
 * - header: Table header cells. Each cell contains the following properties:
 *   - tag: The HTML tag name to use; either 'th' or 'td'.
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the tag.
 *   - content: A localized string for the title of the column.
 *   - field: Field name (required for column sorting).
 *   - sort: Default sort order for this column ("asc" or "desc").
 * - sticky: A flag indicating whether to use a "sticky" table header.
 * - rows: Table rows. Each row contains the following properties:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the <tr> tag.
 *   - data: Table cells.
 *   - no_striping: A flag indicating that the row should receive no
 *     'even / odd' styling. Defaults to FALSE.
 *   - cells: Table cells of the row. Each cell contains the following keys:
 *     - tag: The HTML tag name to use; either 'th' or 'td'.
 *     - attributes: Any HTML attributes, such as "colspan", to apply to the
 *       table cell.
 *     - content: The string to display in the table cell.
 *     - active_table_sort: A boolean indicating whether the cell is the active
         table sort.
 * - footer: Table footer rows, in the same format as the rows variable.
 * - empty: The message to display in an extra row if table does not have
 *   any rows.
 * - no_striping: A boolean indicating that the row should receive no striping.
 * - header_columns: The number of columns in the header.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_table()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
```

Comment: This not enougth.
i set sticky=true, but it's not working.